# How can I message voice memos on iPad to be sent at a future date?

Tags: ipad, calendar, voice-memo

I am using an iPad Pro 2020. I do daily voice memos. I would like to record voice messages and have them sent at a future date and time through my email or otherwise through, say, iPad calendar.

Is that possible and how would I do it?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. Have you tried doing it?

Comment: In Google Mail, one can use the Schedule Send function, but the set up is purely manual, so far as I can tell.